# Issue passing options for a representable - wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to use passing options in [representers gem](https://github.com/apotonick/representable#passing-options)

I have a decorator:

```
class ProductDecorator < Representable::Decorator
  include Representable::JSON

  property :code
  property :name

  property :store_id, getter: lambda { |opts| opts[:store_id] },
    type: Integer

  property :url, decorator_scope: true, getter: lambda { |options|
    File.join(options.fetch(:site,""), url)
  }, type: String

  def url
    File.join(represented.path ,"p")
  end

end
```

But when I try to pass my options using:

```
ProductDecorator.new(product).
        to_hash(store_id: 1, site: "my_url")
```

I'm getting the message `wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)`

I've tried many options, but I could find what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`to_hash` method doesn't take arguments that is the reason for error.

I suppose you meant to do something like:

```
ProductDecorator.new(product).to_json(store_id: 1, site: "my_url")
```

Or you can also go for:

```
JSON.parse(ProductDecorator.new(product).
to_json(store_id: 1, site: "my_url")).symbolize_keys
```

Comment: This is not possible. I have to pass my object to be represented in the `new` parameter

Comment: Alright. What exactly are you trying to do with `(store_id: 1, site: "my_url")` part?

Comment: These items are not from my origin model `product` but I have to insert it in my representable. That's why i'm adding it.

Comment: Thanks! I endup using `JSON.parse(ProductDecorator.new(product).
            to_json(store_id: @store.id, site: @store.url)).symbolize_keys`